# What does "make spoons" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Pulp Fiction (1994)*, Butch just reached home after boxing match:

> Fabienne: Can you **make spoons**?
>
> Butch: You know what? I was thinkin' about takin' a shower. I'm
> stinkin' like a dog over here.
>
> Fabienne: I like the way you stink.

What does "make spoons" mean?

Comment: This is deliberately incorrect English. Fabienne was not a native speaker and had a strong accent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably refers to this

[Merriam-Webster "spooning"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spooning)
to nestle close together while lying down with one person facing the back of another

Comment: It's spoons (plural) not +ing.

Comment: So it is. And as I said, it probably refers to "spooning".

Answer (score 5):

Here's the scene, for reference - without which this question doesn't make much sense: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2TAmGmsw-o

As the previous answer guesses, Fabienne wanted Butch to spoon her.  We do not typically say "make spoons" to refer to spooning. Fabienne speaks with an obvious accent and we're meant to understand that her English isn't entirely fluent.  Look at the next bit of dialogue in this scene:

> Fabienne: I was looking at myself in the mirror...
>
> Butch: Uh-huh
>
> Fabienne: I wish I had a pot.
>
> Butch: You were looking at yourself in the mirror and you wished you had some pot?
>
> Fabienne: *A* pot. A pot belly.

Native English speakers do not call pot bellies *pots*, just as we don't say "make spoons."  This time, Butch doesn't understand the mistake and asks her about it.